# Permalinks - Different structures for different categories?

Tags: categories, permalinks

Currently I use /%category%/%postname%/ as my permalink structure. However, I would like to have a different structure for different categories. This is because I have a "News" blog that I would like to have organized by date like this - /2011/10/02/. But I have other categories where I do not want a date structure at all.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably not possible or it would require some really scary and fragile hacks. Use a custom taxonomy for the news or a custom post type instead. Setting a different permalink structure for these is much easier. You should find enough examples on our site.

Comment: +1 for custom taxonomy, as this is how I've solved the same problem several times.