# A different permalink structure for different categories

Tags: categories, permalinks, url-rewriting, urls, slug

My *Settings > Permalinks* is set to `/%category%/%postname%/`. Thus blog posts have URLs like `example.com/category12/article1`. I would like to **keep this permalink structure for most articles**.

Which PHP function should I modify (I'll override it in the theme `functions.php`) to set **an empty slug** for a specific category named `empty`, and only for this one? I'd like articles of this precise category `empty` to have URLs like `example.com/article2`.

How to do this in the PHP code (without using a plugin)?

Said differently, how to have permalinks `/%category%/%postname%/` for all categories except one category which should have `/%postname%/` permalinks?

In the answer of [Permalinks - Different structures for different categories?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30053/permalinks-different-structures-for-different-categories) (I cannot comment there because I don't have enough reputation), it is said to create a new taxonomy. But how to set different permalinks for a new taxonomy?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option for adding custom structure you can select the checkbox and Permalink is generated like this example.com/article2. and there is also a product permalink that is also customizable.

Edit

There is an option for setting permalink in WordPress setting you can select "post name" check box for getting only post name in URL and create custom permalink.[image: Screenshot]

and also visit this page for more information https://wordpress.org/support/article/settings-permalinks-screen/

Comment: Thank you. Can you please add more details? Which checkbox (maybe you can add a screenshot)? Which "custom structure"? Which "product permalink"? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not answer the question. `%category%/%post_name%` should be kept for all articles of all categories except one category, for which articles should have permalinks `%post_name%`.